# VW 2012 Jetta Sportwagon 2.0L TDI clunk in stearing wheel

Tags: vw, noise, power-steering, jetta, steering-wheel

I have a VW 2012 Jetta Sportwagon 2.0L TDI and have been dealing with a strange clunk/pop in the steering wheel. Have been to the dealership about this matter twice. The first response from the dealer was that the front struts and sway bar links needed to be replaced. Understandable and I agreed to have them replaced. A week after the repair, the noise returned. Went back to the dealership. They now responded that the belly tray for oil was loose and that noise was my front driver-side tire was hitting it. The noise went away for a couple weeks. Now the noise is back and I don't know what to do now.

This isn't about me complaining about the dealership. I want to know what this noise is. It could possibly be the tires moving on the pavement. But, like I said before, I just don't know.

To reproduce the noise, I simply have the car stopped while I'm driving it or place it in park in my driveway. The noise occurs only when I move the steering wheel back and forth. It's like a slight clunk and pop. While driving, I don't hear or feel anything. I hear the noise and feel the clunk in the wheel and the breaks while the vehicle is in stand still.

My best guess is that a pump or maybe the bearings in the steering wheel are going.

Any suggestions or help will be very grateful. I will be making an appointment somewhere else very soon to get this looked at.